# Is a UI/Start entry required for a Windows Store app?

Tags: windows-store-apps

Can a “modern”/Universal Windows app distributed through the Windows Store be installed without creating a Start menu entry for itself? What I’m thinking of making is more of a helper app that you never actually want to open directly, so it seems meaningless to have an app icon for it in Start.

Answer (score 0):

UI/Start entry required for Windows Store app, It is impossible for you to let installed app disappear in the start menu.